# How to create a functioning conditional submit box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a bit of a newbie building a guessing game and having some trouble figuring out how to get my second submit form to work.

First, I populate a random deck of cards, and have the user guess how many there are. Then I want the user to guess how many hearts are in the deck. My code looks like the following:
HTML:

```
<body>
<h1>Pick a card, any card</h1>
<p id="instructions"> You have two boxes of cards, but you might not be playing with full decks. How many cards do you actually have? </p>  
  <form id="game-input">
    <input type="text" id="guess" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
  <p id="tally"></p>
  <p id="result"></p>
  <h4 id="heartGame"></h4>
  <p id="heart-placeholder"></p>
  <p id="heartResult"></p>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
// Variable for a guess tally
var guessTally = 1;

// Let's create arrays for card attributes
var suits = ["H", "D", "S", "C"];
var ranks = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"];

// Card class constructor
var Card = function() {
  var randomSuit = Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length);
  var randomRank = Math.floor(Math.random()*ranks.length);
  var card = {
    suit: suits[randomSuit],
    rank: ranks[randomRank]
  };
  return card;
};

// Now we create a deck object (we'll only need one, so we don't need a constructor here)
var cardDeck = {
  cards: [],
  capacity: 2,
  popDeck: function() {
    var answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.capacity + 1);
    while(this.cards.length < answer) {
    this.cards.push(new Card());
    }
  },
  testDeck: function() {
    console.log("Our deck has " + this.cards.length + " cards in it");
  }
};

// Now, let's write a function for the actual guessing game
var game = {
  init: function(){
    $("#game-input").on("submit", function() {
  var message;
      var nextGame = "Now that you've won, guess how many hearts are in the deck:";
      var heartHTML = '<form id="heart-input"><input type="text" id="heartGuess"/><input type="submit" /></form>';
  var tallyMessage = "Total guesses: " + guessTally;
  var guess = $("#guess").val();

// Logic for what to do while guessing
   if (guess == cardDeck.cards.length && guessTally === 1) {
    message = "Good job, you got it! It took you " + guessTally + " guess!";
    $("#heartGame").html(nextGame);
    $("#heart-placeholder").html(heartHTML);

  } else if (guess == cardDeck.cards.length && guessTally > 1) {
    message = "Good job, you got it! It took you " + guessTally + " guesses.";
    $("#heartGame").html(nextGame);
    $("#heart-placeholder").html(heartHTML);

  } else if (guess > cardDeck.cards.length) {
    message = "You guessed " + guess + ". Sorry, your guess was too high, you'll have to try again.";
    guessTally++;

  } else if (guess < cardDeck.cards.length) {
    message = "You guessed " + guess + ". Whoops, looks like you guessed low";
    guessTally++;

  } else if (isNaN(guess)) {
    message = "Please guess using a number.";
  }
  $("#tally").html(tallyMessage);    
  $("#result").html(message);
  return false;
    });
  }
};

//Count for the individual suits
var suitCount = {
  hearts:   0,  
  spades:   0,
  clubs:    0,
  diamonds: 0,
  count:    function(){
    i = 0;
    for (i; i < cardDeck.cards.length; i++) {
      if (cardDeck.cards[i].suit === "H") {
        this.hearts++;
      } else if (cardDeck.cards[i].suit === "S") {
        this.spades++;         
      } else if (cardDeck.cards[i].suit === "C") {
        this.clubs++;
      } else if (cardDeck.cards[i].suit === "D") {
        this.diamonds++;
      }
    }
  }  
};

//Logic for Heart count game
var suitGame = {
  init: function(){
    $("#heart-input").on("submit", function() {
  var heartMessage;
  var heartGuess = $("#heartGuess").val();
  var diff = suitCount.hearts - heartGuess;

 //Logic for guessing heart count
  if (diff < 0) {
    heartMessage = ("Too low");
  } else if (diff > 0) {
    heartMessage = ("Too high");
  } else if (diff === 0) {
    heartMessage = ("Got it");
  }

    $("#heartResult").html(heartMessage);
    return false;
    });
  }
};

cardDeck.popDeck();
suitCount.count();
game.init();
suitGame.init();
```

Please forgive my verbosity, just trying to be thorough!

Comment: I have zero difficulty getting your code to do multiple submits here: http://jsfiddle.net/VtgLa/. What sort of error are you getting if any? What doesn't work for you? Everything you wrote looks valid and seems to work just fine.

Comment: @gfish3000 It does appear to work, sorry I wasn't more clear. In that jsfiddle example, the page refreshes/breaks on submission to the second box. Expected behavior is that it will return a result to heartResult based on the logic of suitGame.init() and not crash the page.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be using === instead of ==. I've not seen === used before, and == means equal to?. The = is used to set values, while == checks if two values are equal, as far as I can tell, === has no uses.

Comment: I don't believe this is the problem. === Is used to enforce whether or not the left is literally equal to the right, whereas == can sometimes give some funky-feeling behavior depending on what your comparison type is. For more info, check out this [article on '=='](https://medium.com/p/8f408c26ecf1).